# Generating PS1 in bash function

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to display the version of Node in my bash command prompt. I created a function to generate that portion of PS1. It gets the major version of Node, and colors it based on its numeric value. In my `.bash_profile`:

```bash
nv_ps1 () {
  nv_re="v([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]"
  if [[ $($NVM_BIN/node --version) =~ $nv_re ]]; then
    nv_major=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    let nv_color=$nv_major+26
    echo "\[\e[${nv_color}m\]$nv_major\[\e[m\]"
  fi
}

export PS1="[\$(nv_ps1) \[\e[36m\]\t\[\e[m\] \W]\\$ "
```

The escape sequences in the function output don't get evaluated, though, and the command prompt ends up looking like this:

```
[\[\e[34m\]8\[\e[m\] 08:54:58 ~]$
```

How can i get this to work?

Comment: Consider using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to build the value of `PS1` rather than embedding commands in the prompt itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell evaluate escaped chars before running the command *nv_ps1*.  So this command should not output escaped chars, they will just be displayed verbatim.  Ascii codes (colors) can be outputted by *nv_ps1* if you convert them before, that's why `echo -e` seems to be enough.  But `\[` and `\]` are specific to *PS1* interpretation, you have no way to output them from your function.  You can ignore this, but you may be disappointed sooner or later.

The simplest solution is `export PS1="[$(nv_ps1) \[\e[36m\]\t\[\e[m\] \W]\\$ "`.  Thus, escaped chars are stored directly in *PS1* on assignment.
Advantage : Only evaluate *nv_ps1* once, so the shell do not fork on every prompt.
Drawback : Only evaluate *nv_ps1* once, so if Node is updated, currently open shells prompt would not (but you can `source ~/.bashrc`).

If you really want to keep the prompt up to date, you must have two functions calls `export PS1="[\[\$(nv_ps1 color)\]\$(nv_ps1 version)\[\e[m\] \[\e[36m\]\t\[\e[m\] \W]\\$ "`, and put this in your function `[[ $1 == color ]] && printf "\e[${nv_color}m" || printf "${nv_major}"`.

Side notes :

- Exporting PS1 is not necessary.
- Using local variables is preferred :

  ```
  local nv_re="v([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]"
  local nv_major="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  local nv_color=$((nv_major + 26))
  ```

Answer (score -1):

In your function `nv_ps1`, try with `echo -e "\033[${nv_color}m${nv_major}\033[0m"`, it should be better

Comment: Nope, i still get the same thing...

Comment: exactly the same? in your case I'm pretty sure you have to set the '-e' to evaluate colors :
[vm-test-lnx 18:24:38 ~]# echo "[\033[0;31mtest\033[0m]"
[\033[0;31mtest\033[0m]
[vm-test-lnx 18:24:41 ~]# echo -e "[\033[0;31mtest\033[0m]"
[test]

I'm doing some tests and I'll come back

Comment: Try with :

echo -e "\033[${nv_color}m${nv_major}\033[0m"

Please also verify the output of your term by doing "echo $TERM"